# Newton's Method, stuck on iteration 2

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization, operations-research

Is the point of Newton's Method for finding a local minimum of a function to find critical and saddle points of a function, or is it to find the true minima? I am using Newton's Method on the function $f(x)=x^4+4x^2y+4y^2+2x+2y$ starting at the point $(1,1)$ and am confused by the results I'm getting. After my first iteration, I am at $(x,y)=(1,-3/4)$ with a function value of $3/4$. I get a gradient of $0$ on my second iteration, though, so I don't move anywhere after that. Using WolframAlpha, I saw that this point is a saddle point of the function, so I didn't know if that is what Newton's Method is all about or if I'm doing something wrong.

There are smaller function values. For example, $(-2,-2)$ has a function value of $-8$.

Comment: Newton's method will give you the point where the derivative is zero. Depending on the starting point you can get to a local min/max as well.

Comment: @novice so the magnitude of every subsequent gradient in each iteration using Newton's method should decrease is what you're saying? I should keep getting a smaller and smaller step size until I find a gradient of 0?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method_in_optimization

Comment: Newton's method finds points where $\nabla f(x) = 0$, which could be saddle points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's rather unusual to hit a critical point exactly after one iteration of Newton's method: in this example it only happens if you start at a point 
of the form $(1,y)$.  More typically, you might converge to a critical point
as you take more and more iterations, or not converge at all: periodic or chaotic behaviour is possible.  For example, there is a $2$-cycle: start at 
$(5/4, -29/32)$, the first iteration takes you to $(3/4, -13/32)$ and the second takes you back to $(5/4, -29/32)$.

In this particular problem, $(1,-3/4)$ is the only critical point; there are no local minima or maxima.